# Customizing color of the header in flextable?

Tags: r, flextable

How can I change the color of my header in my flextable? I'm looking for the equivalent to this in the old FlexTable:

`MyFTable <- setFlexTableBackgroundColors(MyFTable, i = 1 , j = 4, colors = "grey", to = "header")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should produce what you want:

```
MyFtable <- bg(i = 1, j = 4, bg = "grey", part = "header")
```

For future reference, all of the functions  of `flextable` are very well documented at https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/overview.html - helped me a ton!